# Implicit function theorem and a tangent

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, tangent-line, implicit-function-theorem

> Show that the equation $x^3 - 2x + 2y^3 + y^2 = 0$ defines a curve of the form ${(x, y) : x = \varphi(y)}$ in $B^2
> ((0, 0), \delta)$ form some $\delta > 0$. Find the equation of the tangent at $(0,0)$

The first part is just an application of the implicit function theorem.

Since $F(x,y) = x^3 - 2x + 2y^3 + y^2$ and $F(0,0) = 0$, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(0,0) = -2 \ne 0.$ There exist an $x = \varphi(y)$.

For the second part I'm familiar that the derivative for $\varphi(y)$ is $\varphi'(y) = - \frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}$, but I'm not sure if this is the tangent they're referring to?

Comment: The tangent is given by $x=\varphi‘(0)y+\varphi(0)$

Comment: @Fakemistake How did you get this result? I'm getting that $x-x_0 = \varphi'(y)(y-y_0) \Rightarrow x = \varphi'(y)y$ if $(x_0, y_0) = (0,0)$

Comment: $x^3 - 2x + 2y^3 + y^2 = 0$ has tangent cone $-2x=0$ hence tangent $x=0$ at the origin.